# how to autoincrement a string value fetch from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field `outlet_id` having values like this:

```
AA1
AA2
AA3
AA4
```

It's not mysql auto incrementing field. I have to fetch the last value inserted into the `outlet_id` and increment it like AA5,AA6,AA7 ...

What I have done so far is:

```
$sql_outlet_id=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(outlet_id) FROM outlets");
$val = mysql_fetch_row($sql_outlet_id);
$new_array = explode('AA',$val[0]);

echo $outlet_id=$new_array[1]+1;
```

Output always shows 10 even if last inserted id is AA20 or AA21 or so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$val = 'AA4';

$temp= str_replace('AA', '', $val);

$new = 'AA' . ($temp + 1);

echo $new;
```

**Output**

```
AA5
```

Comment: how to fetch the last value from database like AA4 @sougata

Comment: Is there any field that is auto incremented? like `id`, `date` or something like this?

Comment: ya i got it id is auto incremented.